# NGINX redirect domain but without specific directory

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

`www.domain.com`

I want to redirect thats domain to www.domain.net like that
`www.domain.com` redirect
`www.domain.com/dev` no redirect for specific dev directory
`www.domain.com/?page-id=4` redirect
`www.domain.com/test` also redirect

General I want redirect all requests to domain.net but if it is `domain.com/dev`it should not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx uses the most specific location it can, so if you add a catch all block to redirect to .net like:

```
location / {
    # redirect to .net
}
```

And then a specific location like

```
location /dev {
    # handle as usual
}
```

Then any requests that dont match /dev will get redirected, and any that match dev will.

Comment: nope. I found that. It works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478694/nginx-redirect-all-http-to-https-with-one-exception

Comment: This one:
`listen 80;
location / {
    if ($request_uri !~ /preview) {
        return 302 https://...;
    }
}`

Comment: You should avoid 'if' if possible https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/